# Agregar div a partir de un json

Tags: javascript, html, json

Quiero agregar una etiqueta de descuento en productos con ciertas id, como este por ejemplo

```
<article productid="13516">
    <div class="listItem">
        <a class="item-image" title="" href="">    
            <div class="flags">
                  <div class="discount"></div>
                  <div class="highlight"></div>
            </div>
</article>
```

estoy filtrando las id del json para que se me muestren en consola, pero la pregunta es, se puede agregar un elemento a las id que filtro?, intente hacerlo con el append, pero pues no me funciono.

````
window.onload = function() {

    let filters = {
        productId: ["13516", "14753", "12980"]
    };

    const options = {
      method: 'GET',
      //mode: 'no-cors'
    };
    const url = 'url de la api'
    fetch(url, options)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data =>{
        //console.log(data)
        var mJson = data;

        function multiFilter(array, filters) {
          let filterKeys = Object.keys(filters);
          return array.filter((item) => filterKeys.every((key) => (filters[key].indexOf(item[key]) !== -1)));
        }
        var result = multiFilter(mJson, filters);
        console.log(result);

        var $flagHighligthContainer = $(result).find('.highlight');
        var $productDiscount = $('<p>').addClass('flag flag-envio-gratis').html('Envio Gratis');
        $flagHighligthContainer.empty().append($productDiscount );
     })
}
```
````

Comment: Podriás agregar tu código html? Para poder tener un visión completa.

Comment: listo ya la edite

Comment: no, lo que quiero es añadir un div a las id que están en let filters

Comment: No se entiende muy bien tu pregunta, ni por qué hay tantos divs anidados dentro de `article` que no hacen nada ¿? ¿No sería mejor asignar una clase a `article` y luego por CSS poner lo que quieras a los `article` que sean parte del filtro?

Comment: lo que esta dentro de article es algo que trae por defecto el CMS, y necesito es agarrar el id que esta en productid, para agregar el flag a productos específicos